# How to get the selected CollectionViewCell in the UICollectionView?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I am new for IOS development , and I try to use `UIcollectionView` to show the photo without using `storyboard`.

I create a `xib file` call `AITFileCell_grid.xib` , and add a `Collection View Cell`.

I also create another `xib file` and add the `Collection View` for loading `Collection View Cell`.

I want to selected multiple file and delete them by `delete button`.

But I can not get the cell when I click the `delete button` by following code.

```
if(self.collectionView.indexPathsForSelectedItems > 0){
        NSLog(@"indexPathsForSelectedItems...count.%@..@@@" , self.collectionView.indexPathsForSelectedItems);


        for(NSIndexPath *indexPath in self.collectionView.indexPathsForSelectedItems){

//            [self.collectionView deselectItemAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:NO];
            NSString *filePath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@", directory, [fileList objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
            [[NSFileManager defaultManager] removeItemAtPath:filePath error:nil] ;
            AITFileCell_grid *cell = [self.collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"AITFileCell_grid" forIndexPath:indexPath];
        }
    }
```

But the sell seems not correct...

**How to get the `selected cell` in `collectionView`** ?

Comment: First give tag like `delete.tag =indexpath.item` and then maintain array when you select. after that when you want to delete than using for loop you can remove data from array and just `[collectionview reloaddata]`.

Answer (score 2):

Usually your delete button should have a selector like this:

```
deleteButton = [[UIButton alloc] init];
...
[deleteButton addTarget:self selector:@sel(buttonPressed:) forControlEvent:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

I believe you can get the indexPath using the following:

```
-(void)buttonPressed:(id)sender
{
    UIButton *button = (UIButton *)sender;

    CGPoint rootPoint = [button convertPoint:CGPointZero toView:self.collectionView];

    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.collectionView indexPathForItemAtPoint:rootPoint];

    // -----------------------------------------------------------------
    // Now you have your indexPath, you can delete your item
    // -----------------------------------------------------------------



    // first update your data source, in this case, I assume your data source 
    // is a list of values stored inside a NSArray

    NSMutableArray *updatedList = [self.myListData mutableCopy];

    [updatedList removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    self.myListData = updatedList;


    // now update your interface

    [self.collectionView performBatchUpdates:^{
        [self.collectionView deleteItemsAtIndexPath:@[indexPath]];
    }];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

For checking which Collection Cell is clicked, you can use this delegate method in your Controller.

```
-(void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView didSelectItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    int itemNo = (int)[indexPath row]+1;
    CollectionCell *selectedCell =(CollectionCell*)[collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    switch (itemNo) {
        case 1:
        {
            //your Logic for 1st Cell
            break;
        }
        case 2:
        {
            //your Logic for 2nd Cell
            break;
        }
        .
        .
        .
    }
}
```