# How to fetch CollectionViewCell details on clicking button?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibutton, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I have gone through both

[How to get the selected CollectionViewCell in the UICollectionView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24298609/how-to-get-the-selected-collectionviewcell-in-the-uicollectionview)

[how to access from UICollectionViewCell the indexPath of the Cell in UICollectionView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13875428/how-to-access-from-uicollectionviewcell-the-indexpath-of-the-cell-in-uicollectio)

But my question is little bit different from the above two.

I have review button on mybookingsCell which is from nearByCollectionView

```
- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)cv cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

   DetailObject * Obj=[[DetailObject alloc]init];

   Obj=[self.listOfObjects objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];  

  // DetailObject is NSObject class and listOfObjects getting values from API 
  // mybookingsCell.headerLabel.text=Obj.name; like this i am putting the values in cell 

    NearbyCell *mybookingsCell = (NearbyCell *)[cv dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"nearby" forIndexPath:indexPath];

  [mybookingsCell.reviewBtn addTarget:self action:@selector(didTapReviewBtn:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];
}

-(IBAction)didTapReviewBtn:(id)sender
{

}
```

On clicking review button i need details which are on the cell. 
I tried like this

```
-(IBAction)didTapReviewBtn:(id)sender
{
  NearbyCell *clickedCell = (NearbyCell *)[[sender superview] superview];
  NSIndexPath *clickedButtonIndexPath = [self.nearByCollectionView indexPathForCell:clickedCell]; 
}
```

But my application is crashing. So help me how can i fetch cell details with corresponding click on button.

Comment: `UITableView` and `UICollectionView` both support this behavior as mentioned in the duplicate.

Comment: Remove the alloc/init of DetailObject in `collectionView: cellForItemAtIndexPath:`. If application is crashing, you should have an error message. Did you check that [[sender superView] superview] is indeed a `NearByCell` object?

Comment: @iosDev82 Read question properly http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7504421/getting-row-of-uitableview-cell-on-button-press before you commenting. He is saying " The problem is I don't know how to know on which cell a button is being pressed." Mine is different. Don't do downvote easily

Comment: @ShrikantKankatti Please go through the link that I've posted and see this answer here http://stackoverflow.com/a/16270198/1891327. I KNOW your issue can get fixed this way. And don't use `superView.superView`, since it can vary from cell to cell.

Comment: @iosDev82 i know that is wrong that is the reason  i came here, putting my code which i have tried.

Comment: @ShrikantKankatti So the link that I've posted doesn't help you?

Comment: @Larme yeah i removed those lines. I have updated UIButton *btn=sender;
      NSLog("%@",[self.listOfObjects objectAtIndex:btn.tag];);  it worked for me :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code to Click Button and get Get Data;

```
- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)cv cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

   DetailObject * Obj=[[DetailObject alloc]init];

   Obj=[self.listOfObjects objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];  

  // DetailObject is NSObject class and listOfObjects getting values from API 
  // mybookingsCell.headerLabel.text=Obj.name; like this i am putting the values in cell 

    NearbyCell *mybookingsCell = (NearbyCell *)[cv dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"nearby" forIndexPath:indexPath];

  [mybookingsCell.reviewBtn addTarget:self action:@selector(didTapReviewBtn:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];
mybookingsCell.reviewBtn.tag=indexPath.row;
}

-(IBAction)didTapReviewBtn:(id)sender
{
      UIButton *btn=sender;
      NSLog("%@",[self.listOfObjects objectAtIndex:btn.tag];); // fetch you cell data here and use it
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I have made changes in your code

```
- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)cv cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

       DetailObject * Obj=[[DetailObject alloc]init];

       Obj=[self.listOfObjects objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];  

      // DetailObject is NSObject class and listOfObjects getting values from API 
      // mybookingsCell.headerLabel.text=Obj.name; like this i am putting the values in cell 

        NearbyCell *mybookingsCell = (NearbyCell *)[cv dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"nearby" forIndexPath:indexPath];

      [mybookingsCell.reviewBtn addTarget:self action:@selector(didTapReviewBtn:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];
      mybookingsCell.reviewBtn.tag = indexPath.row;
}

-(IBAction)didTapReviewBtn:(id)sender
{
  NearbyCell *clickedCell = (NearbyCell *)[[sender superview] superview];
  int *clickedButtonIndexPathRow = (UIButton*)sender.tag;
  // Using this you can get data from your data source arrray.
}
```